# Why in the world is this causing a java.lang.NullPointerException?

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception

```
String filelist1[];
filelist1 = null;

for (String s : step1) {
    if(s != null || !"".equals(s)) {
        on = s.split(":");

        if("FILE".equals(on[0])) {
            filelist1[i] = on[1];
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Why does this cause a NullPointerException? I've determined that it's something to do with `filelist1[i] = on[1];`, and even further that it is only the `filelist1` array.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: `filelist` is null, so a NullPointerException is thrown when you attempt to set a value to one of its indices.

Comment: Why in the world you try to set something that is *by default initialized into `null`* to `null`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
filelist1 = null;
```

Then you try to set `filelist1[i] = ...` ... it's `null`, it's not an array!

Use an `ArrayList` instead.

```
ArrayList<String> filelist1 = new ArrayList<String>();

...
filelist1.add(on[1]);
```